# Javascript to change Request Header: accept-language parameter

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, request-headers

I have an AJAX call that returns a list of places by name. I want these names to be strictly in English, but the API returns the name in the language of the request header's accept-language parameter. Some users have their browser's default language set to something other than English.

I am not familiar with this so I wanted to know if it is possible (in javascript or ruby) to alter the request header's accept-language parameter so that it is always English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,fr-CA");
```

Comment: To be an effective answer please provide some details.

Answer (score 1):

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept-Language','en-US')
```